# Octave how change format of matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

I would please like your help in one of my assignments.

I have the following octave code:

```
close all;
clc;
pkg load image;
pkg load signal;


bestsize = 299900;
%Creating metrics matrix with zeros
metrics = zeros(2,8,20,19); 


for i = 1:2

    filename = sprintf('sub%03d.csv', i ); %All data must have the same name pattern

    %Remove first row and first column
    patient = dlmread(filename,';',1,1);
    sizepat = size(patient,1);
    if sizepat <= bestsize
    %patient is a 299900x19 matrix. Adding 100 zeros at the end of each channel for easier comptuting
        patient0 = padarray(patient,[300000-sizepat,0],0,"post");
    else
        patient0 = patient(1:bestsize, 1:19);
        patient0 = padarray(patient0,[100,0],0,"post");
    end
    %patient1 is a 20(epochs)X15000(values)X19*channels) matrix
    patient1 = reshape(patient0,20,15000,19);
    %patient1 is a matrix with 20 columns and 15000 rows, repeated 19 times

    for j = 1:20
        for k = 1:19
            metrics(i,1,j,k) = max(patient1(:,j,k)); %Max value
            metrics(i,2,j,k) = min(patient1(:,j,k)); %Min value
            metrics(i,3,j,k) = mean(patient1(:,j,k)); %Mean value
            metrics(i,4,j,k) = std(patient1(:,j,k)); %Std value
            metrics(i,5,j,k) = var(patient1(:,j,k)); %Variance value
            metrics(i,6,j,k) = kurtosis(patient1(:,j,k)); %Kurtosis value
            metrics(i,7,j,k) = skewness(patient1(:,j,k)); %Skewness value
            metrics(i,8,j,k) = peak2peak(patient1(:,j,k)); %Peak to peak value
        end
    end
end


% Save data
save("metrics.mat","metrics");
```

So the previous code takes as input the data of an EEG for 2 patients. Each patient has 19 electrodes in his head. We split the data into 20 epochs. The script produces the metrics matrix with has the following format:

```
 metrics =

ans(:,:,1,1) =

   ......

ans(:,:,2,1) =

    ....

ans(:,:,3,1) =

  .....

.....

ans(:,:,20,1) =

  .....

ans(:,:,1,2) =

   ......

ans(:,:,2,2) =

    ....

ans(:,:,3,2) =

  .....

.....

ans(:,:,20,2) =

  .....
```

What i need to do is change the way the metrics matrix presents the data. Instead of showing the data this way in multiple different matrices i need them to be shown in a single matrix like this:

```
 metrics =

FIRST ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,1,1)
SECOND ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,2,1)
THIRD ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,3,1)
......
TWENTIETH ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,20,1)
TWENTY FIRST ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,1,2)
TWENTY SECOND ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,2,2)
TWENTY THIRD ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,3,2)
.......
FORTIETH ROW THESE VALUES -> ans(:,:,20,2)
```

Can you please help me fix the script to show the results this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the function `reshape`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the 'solution':

```
tmp = reshape( matrices, [ size( matrices )(1:2), prod( size( matrices )(3:4) ) ] )
tmp = permute( tmp, [3, 1, 2] )
Out = tmp(:,:)
```

Explanation:

- use 'reshape' to convert your 4D `A x B x C x D` matrix into a 3D `A x B x (C*D)` one.
- use 'permute' to obtain the 'transposed' `(C*D) x A x B` matrix.
- use the colon operator, but calling only 2 dimensions instead of the full 3: this causes the remainder dimensions to be concatenated into one (in column major order). In other words, you will represent the `(C*D) x A x B` matrix as `(C*D) x (A*B)`. (or alternatively you could perform another reshape operation)

---

<sub>CAVEAT: In general, when using octave, vectorised operations such as the above work much better (i.e. faster) than for-loops. However, in some cases, if you're dealing with very VERY large matrices, where performing these operations on limited memory will result in a lot of memory acrobatics to achieve the necessary allocations, it may actually be faster to simply do a simple for-loop. So it's always worth benchmarking both approaches for your particular data.</sub>