# Octave How Print Each result of Matrix in next row

Tags: octave

I would please like your help.

I have created a double for loop which writes some date in a matrix called "metrics". The code is the following (dont bother about what i is):

```
for j = 1:20
        for k = 1:19
            metrics(i,1,j,k) = max(patient1(:,j,k)); %Max value
            metrics(i,2,j,k) = min(patient1(:,j,k)); %Min value
            metrics(i,3,j,k) = mean(patient1(:,j,k)); %Mean value
            metrics(i,4,j,k) = std(patient1(:,j,k)); %Std value
            metrics(i,5,j,k) = var(patient1(:,j,k)); %Variance value
            metrics(i,6,j,k) = kurtosis(patient1(:,j,k)); %Kurtosis value
            metrics(i,7,j,k) = skewness(patient1(:,j,k)); %Skewness value
            metrics(i,8,j,k) = peak2peak(patient1(:,j,k)); %Peak to peak value
        end
    end
```

This script produces the results i want but not in the way i want them. It prints all the data next to each other in the same row of the metrics matrix.

I want for j=1 the k=1:19 to be printed in the first row of the metrics matrix, for j=2 the k=1:19 to be printed in the second row of the matrix etc.

Can you please help me?

Thanks

Comment: You use the word "printed", but none of your code "prints" anything. You mean just storing it in the `metrics` matrix? If so, what is stopping you from changing the indices? or doing `permute` in the end, to change the dimension location?

Comment: use `permute`. the exact way in which you should use it depends one what you want to do with i and j.

Comment: How is this question different from your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76302148/7328782

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite understand your problem, but I think you should change the order or position of the indexes...
See and run the example below...

```
clear

# Imagine Five sets with Four 2x3 arrays each...
nrows = 2
ncols = 3
narrays = 4
nsets = 5

u = zeros(nrows, ncols, narrays, nsets)

# assign the 1st row of 1st array at/in 1st set
u(1,:,1,1) = [1, 2, 3]
printf('The 1st array of 1st set:\n')
disp(u(:,:,1,1))

# assign the 2nd row of 3rd array at/in 4th set
u(2,:,3,4) = [4, 5, 6]
printf('\nThe 3rd array of 4th set:\n')
disp(u(:,:,3,4))

# assign the 3rd column of 2nd array at/in 5th set
u(:,3,2,5) = [7, 8]
printf('\nThe 2nd array of 5th set:\n')
disp(u(:,:,2,5))

# Check
printf('\n--- The 1st set ---:\n')
disp(u(:,:,:,1))

printf('\n--- The 4th set ---:\n')
disp(u(:,:,:,4))

printf('\n--- The 5th set ---:\n')
disp(u(:,:,:,5))
```